# Where can I find a screw-on tub overflow drain cover?

Tags: bathtub, plumbing-fixture

I'd like to replace this threaded tub overflow drain cover and can't for the life of me find one online that is threaded like this to screw directly onto the 2" PVC pipe rather than working with one or two screws.  What am I missing?  Thank you!

[image: cover]

Comment: "Screw on" isn't an industry term. Try ["threaded"](https://www.google.com/search?q=threaded+tub+overflow+cover&rlz=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Watco innovator Overflow trim kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008B6GQP8)

It has a ring that screws on a 2" thread and the cover snaps on to that.

Comment: thank you!  i think i saw that but didn't realize it worked that way, so i appreciate the clarification!